# How to avoid duplicate key error in swift when iterating over a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm practicing swift and I'm trying to iterate over a Dictionary to print the key, but it gives me a

> fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys

How can remove the error?

```
let people = ["age":14, "age":15, "age":75, "age":43, "age":103, "age":87, "age":12]
for (key, value) in people {
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: you could create an array of dictionaries instead like `[["age":14], ["age":15], ...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each dictionary key MUST be unique

```
let people = ["age1":14, "age2":15, "age3":75, "age4":43, "age5":103, "age6":87, "age7":12]
for (key, value) in people {
    print(value)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a `People` struct or class and use instances of that in an array rather than a dictionary:

```
struct Person {
    var age : Int
}

let people = [Person(age: 14), Person(age: 15)] // and so on

for person in people {
    print(person)
}
```

A dictionary is a mapping of a unique key to some value. Therefore what you previously did was not working because your key `age` was not unique. You can however use a different dictionary:

```
let people = [14: Person(age: 14), 15: Person(age: 15)] // and so on

for (key, value) in people {
    print("\(key) => \(value)")
}
```

Comment: I really like this

Answer (score 2):

As others already said, you **cannot** create a dictionary where the same key does appear more then once.

That said I really like solution provided by `luk2302` because if does offer a well structured approach.

Here I am just adding another solution.

Since the real information in your (wrong) dictionary is the `value` (not the key) what's the meaning of using a `Dictionary`?

You could simply use an array

```
let ages = [14, 15, 75, 43, 103, 87, 12]
ages.forEach { print($0) }
```