# Handling duplicate key values in swift dictionary

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I have to comply with a Restful request call using Swift 3 that unfortunately contains duplicate keys as shown below. I originally placed the data in a dictionary to pass into a JSON serialization call.

```json
       [
          "mid":"3",
          "attributes":[
                "carID":["a":54123,"b":424,"c":"13242"],
                "update":"true"
                "update":"gold" 
          ]
        ]
```

Notice that update occurs twice, which causes this error:

> fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys

I've reviewed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569546/how-to-avoid-duplicate-key-error-in-swift-when-iterating-over-a-dictionary) but doesn't seem to have a pertinent answer.

I thought about using an array but I *think* it would lose the key value pair relationship that I need for the JSON serialization.

I've seen some articles on using structs but I'm not sure that would address the duplicate key issue

Any recommendations? I'm unable to change the parameter names in the request as it is a third party product.

BTW, I don't think my question is a duplicate of [How to avoid duplicate key error in swift when iterating over a dictionary – Ssswift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569546/how-to-avoid-duplicate-key-error-in-swift-when-iterating-over-a-dictionary). That example should truly be a struct/class since it is one key value pair (age:age value) that should be in a class or struct. My example has a repeating key with each of the two instances of the repeating key having different meanings (should they update, and what the updated member type should be). I don't see how it would be applicable but am open to enlightenment on it.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend writing a function that turns the duplicates into an array, since that's the concept you are conveying; multiple values of type update. i.e. "update": ["true", "gold"]

Comment: I don't think the built-in JSON serialization has any way of producing JSON with duplicate keys. I'm also not aware offhand of any third-party JSON serialization for Swift that allows for this (most third-party JSON libraries are just using the built-in `JSONSerialization` anyway; I have a [pure-Swift JSON decoder/encoder](https://github.com/postmates/PMJSON/) but it doesn't let you duplicate keys either). So right now it looks to me like you're going to have to construct the JSON string by hand.

Comment: Also, this is a _really stupid_ API. Most JSON libraries in most languages don't allow for duplicate keys.

Comment: Blame the owner of the web service

Comment: As per JSON standards, unfortunately, nothing prevents from having duplicate keys. Last time, when we got such JSON, we did create array for duplicate key values like @rmooney mentioned above.  At least, that ensures no data is lost.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I agree it is not ideal. I will see if the array approach will work, in terms of producing acceptable JSON structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid duplicate key error in swift when iterating over a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569546/how-to-avoid-duplicate-key-error-in-swift-when-iterating-over-a-dictionary)

Comment: I don't think my question is a duplicate of How to avoid duplicate key error in swift when iterating over a dictionary – Ssswift. That example should truly be a class since it is one key value pair (age) that should be in a class or struct. My example has a repeating key with each of the two instances of the repeating key having different meanings (should they update, and what the new member type should be). I don't see how it would be applicable but am open to enlightenment on it. Thanks

Comment: Question is invalid. Because the JSON given in question is not at all valid JSON. It should be `{ "mid":"3", "attributes": { "carID": {"a":54123,"b":424,"c":"13242" }, "update":["true", "gold"] } }`. This will work. But you are received JSON from api. So only the owner of that API can help you. Good luck.