# Error when I geocode an address (rare) in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, debugging, swiftui

I have a SearchBar that updates a certain Binding string that is the geocoded into a list of potential location matches. Sometimes as I type in a location, I get the following:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report:
->  0x1054f7180 <+0>: pushq  %rbp //Error on this line says "= Thread 1: Fatal Error: Duplicate keys 
    of type 'GeocodedPlacemark' were found in a Dictionary. This usually means either that the type 
    violates Hashable's requirements, or that members of the dictionary were mutated after 
    insertion."
    0x1054f7181 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x1054f7184 <+4>: popq   %rbp
    0x1054f7185 <+5>: retq   
    0x1054f7186 <+6>: nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Only problem is, it gives me no clue as to where the source of the error is...is there some clue in all those numbers or the 'pushq' keyword found on that line that could direct me to the dictionary it is referring to?

Side Note: This error happens maybe once in every 15 or so searches, so it's quite rare.

Search bar code is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox
import MapboxGeocoder

struct SearchBar: View {


var annotation: AnnotationsVM
@State var searchText: String = ""
//@State var typing: Bool = false
@State private var showCancelButton: Bool = false
@ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
@ObservedObject var VModel : ViewModel
@Binding var searchedText: String
@Binding var showResults: Bool
@Binding var showMoreDetails: Bool
var mapStyle: URL

var body: some View {

 let binding = Binding<String>(get: {
    self.searchText
    }, set: {
    self.searchText = $0
    self.searchedText = self.searchText
    self.VModel.findResults(address: self.searchedText)
    if self.VModel.searchResults.count >= 0 {
        self.showResults = true
        self.showMoreDetails = false
    } else {
        self.showResults = false
    }
 }
 )


        return VStack {
            // Search view
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")

                        TextField("search", text: binding, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
                            self.showCancelButton = true
                            self.showMoreDetails = false

                        }, onCommit: {
                            if self.VModel.searchResults.first != nil {
                                self.annotation.addNextAnnotation(address: self.rowText(result: self.VModel.searchResults.first!).label)
                                self.searchedText = "\(self.rowText(result: self.VModel.searchResults.first!).label)"
                            }
                            self.showMoreDetails = false
                            self.showResults = false
                        })

                        Button(action: {
                            self.searchText = ""
                            self.showResults = false
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").opacity(searchText == "" ? 0.0 : 1.0)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
                }

                if showCancelButton  {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        UIApplication.shared.endEditing(true) // this must be placed before the other commands here
                        self.searchText = ""
                        self.showResults = false
                        self.showCancelButton = false
                    }

            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}



private func rowText(result: GeocodedPlacemark) -> (view: Text, label: String) {


//        city is not nil
//        state is not nil
//        country is not nil
        if result.postalAddress != nil && result.postalAddress?.city != "" && result.postalAddress?.state != "" && result.postalAddress?.country != "" {

            return (Text("\(result.formattedName), \(result.postalAddress!.city), \(result.postalAddress!.state), \(result.postalAddress!.country)"), "\(result.formattedName), \(result.postalAddress!.city), \(result.postalAddress!.state), \(result.postalAddress!.country)")
        }



//        city is not nil
//        state is not nil
//        country is nil
        else if result.postalAddress != nil && result.postalAddress?.city != "" && result.postalAddress?.state != "" && result.postalAddress?.country == "" {

            return (Text("\(result.formattedName), \(result.postalAddress!.city), \(result.postalAddress!.state)"), "\(result.formattedName), \(result.postalAddress!.city), \(result.postalAddress!.state)")
        }


//        city is not nil
//        state is nil
//        country is nil
        else if result.postalAddress != nil && result.postalAddress?.city != "" && result.postalAddress?.state == "" && result.postalAddress?.country == "" {

            return (Text("\(result.formattedName), \(result.postalAddress!.city)"), "\(result.formattedName), \(result.postalAddress!.city)")

        }

//More if statements to cover all the different states, this section essentially just returns the way to format the different search results in the search results view (that results view works fine btw)

 }


extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing(_ force: Bool) {
        self.windows
            .filter{$0.isKeyWindow}
            .first?
            .endEditing(force)
    }
}

struct ResignKeyboardOnDragGesture: ViewModifier {
    var gesture = DragGesture().onChanged{_ in
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing(true)
    }
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.gesture(gesture)
    }
}

extension View {
    func resignKeyboardOnDragGesture() -> some View {
        return modifier(ResignKeyboardOnDragGesture())
    }
}
```

The VModel class is as follows:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

@ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
@Published var lat: Double?
@Published var lon: Double?
@Published var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
@Published var name: CLPlacemark?
@Published var searchResults: [GeocodedPlacemark] = []


var userLatitude: CLLocationDegrees {
    return (locationManager.lastLocation?.latitude ?? 0)
}

var userLongitude: CLLocationDegrees {
   return (locationManager.lastLocation?.longitude ?? 0)
}






func getLocation(from address: String, completion: @escaping (_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?)-> Void) {
      //let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let geocoder = Geocoder(accessToken: "pk.eyJ1Ijoibmlja2JyaW5zbWFkZSIsImEiOiJjazh4Y2dzcW4wbnJyM2ZtY2V1d20yOW4wIn0.LY1H3cf7Uz4BhAUz6JmMww")
    let foptions = ForwardGeocodeOptions(query: address)
    print("hit this point")
    foptions.focalLocation = CLLocation(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)
    geocoder.geocode(foptions) { (placemarks, attribution ,error) in
        guard let placemarks = placemarks,
            let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate
        else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
      completion(location)
    }
}




func fetchCoords(address: String, completion: @escaping (Double, Double) -> Void){
    self.getLocation(from: address) { coordinates in
        print(coordinates ?? 0) // Print here
      self.location = coordinates // Assign to a local variable for further processing
        if let lat = coordinates?.latitude, let lon = coordinates?.longitude {
            completion(lat, lon)
        }
    }
}






func findResults(address: String) {
    let geocoder = Geocoder(accessToken: "pk.eyJ1Ijoibmlja2JyaW5zbWFkZSIsImEiOiJjazh4Y2dzcW4wbnJyM2ZtY2V1d20yOW4wIn0.LY1H3cf7Uz4BhAUz6JmMww")
    let foptions = ForwardGeocodeOptions(query: address)
    foptions.focalLocation = CLLocation(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)
    foptions.maximumResultCount = 10
    geocoder.geocode(foptions) { (placemarks, attribution ,error) in
        guard let placemarks = placemarks
        else {
            return
        }
        self.searchResults = []
        for placemark in placemarks {
            self.searchResults.append(placemark)
        }
    }
}
}
```

After setting a Swift Error Breakpoint, it stopped the search in this function (I guess this is a backend MapBox function, because I certainly didn't write it; maybe it comes with the framework?):

```
fileprivate func dataTaskWithURL(_ url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (_ data: Data?) -> Void, errorHandler: @escaping (_ error: NSError) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    return URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let e = error as NSError? {
                    errorHandler(e)
                } else {
                    let unexpectedError = NSError(domain: MBGeocoderErrorDomain, code: -1024, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "unexpected error", NSDebugDescriptionErrorKey : "this error happens when data task return nil data and nil error, which typically is not possible"])
                    errorHandler(unexpectedError)
                }
            }
            return
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            // Handle multiple batch geocoding queries, THE ERROR IS ON THE LINE BELOW and says 'Thread 19: breakpoint 1.1'
            let result = try decoder.decode([GeocodeAPIResult].self, from: data)

            // Check if any of the batch geocoding queries failed
            if let failedResult = result.first(where: { $0.message != nil }) {
                let apiError = Geocoder.descriptiveError(["message": failedResult.message!], response: response, underlyingError: error as NSError?)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    errorHandler(apiError)
                }
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(data)
            }
        } catch {
            // Handle single & single batch geocoding queries
            do {
                let result = try decoder.decode(GeocodeAPIResult.self, from: data)
                // Check if geocoding query failed
                if let message = result.message {
                    let apiError = Geocoder.descriptiveError(["message": message], response: response, underlyingError: error as NSError?)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        errorHandler(apiError)
                    }
                    return

                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler(data)
                }
            } catch {
                // Handle errors that don't return a message (such as a server/network error)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    errorHandler(error as NSError)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show code duding this? It looks like thread-safety issue, so look how you modify data.

Comment: @Asperi it's a big project...how can I locate where this error is originating from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34569563/2382813 does this helps you understand the issue? Can you add the search bar's backend code in question atleast?

Comment: @NikzJon I updated the code, I know it's a lot :/

Comment: Given that the error relates to a dictionary, could you share any code related to dictionary manipulation? It's quite hard to help in this case as the MapBox logic, which is probably the issue, is not here.

Comment: @PranavKasetti I just added the code that is used for the actual geocoding, it's all in the VModel class...

Comment: Based on symptoms (randomly happens, exception itself says that maybe"members of the dictionary were mutated after insertion"), I'd look at multi-threading first. When this exception happens, first of all check on which thread the exception is (for example it can be on Main). Then look what other threads are doing at that time. You might see a correlation, e.g. maybe another thread was reading that map at the time and so on...
You can also create a test which simulates accessing map from different threads (callign the same functions) and see if you get the same exception

Comment: Also, your code still doesn't include the dictionary. Perhaps in `LocationManager`? You may need to remove the unrelated parts of code in all the files for this q.

Comment: LocationManager is just used to retrieve the userLocation; I'm pretty sure it's unrelated to the issue. I almost feel like the dictionary manipulation is happening inside the geocoding functions so I'm not seeing it :/ I'll update the code with the locationManager though

Comment: @KirilS. Hmmm alright, I'll do some research on threading.

Comment: Look at this simple pattern: https://gist.github.com/dmytro-anokhin/4a5848606887871920f539629676d948#file-concurrency_dispatchbarrier-swift (allows synchronous reads, asynchronous barriered writes, very limited code changes). Some people will say this method is not without some loopholes, but it works for most cases... unless you update and read a lot...

Comment: I would also consider setting a Swift Error Breakpoint in Xcode to catch this. Once you get that you can examine which line is the issue

Comment: So....it looks like there is a Mapbox Database Thread, but I've never done any kind of debugging in XCode...anyone have any ideas where I can learn how to properly debug this?

Comment: https://cocoacasts.com/debugging-applications-with-xcode-swift-error-and-exception-breakpoints

Comment: Note that if MapBox is a private framework, or a binary framework, you won't be able to see the line of the error raise.

Comment: I set a Swift Error Breakpoint; it looks like the error is originating from code I didn't write...I'll update my code with this source of error.

Comment: @PranavKasetti any ideas?

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird. My guess is that this is a bug with MapBox, as it is concurrently decoding the data variable in the same function on quick back-to-back searches. I think wrapping that line in `DispatchQueue.global().sync { }` block could work. Not an ideal solution, so I would double-check if you can update MapBox SDK to ensure you have the latest bug free version. I would also wrap your `geocode` function calls inside a `global().sync { }` block to be safe.

Comment: @PranavKasetti Wrap which line with DispatchQueue.global().sync {} ? I believe I can update MapBox to the latest version. If you post your suggested solution, I'll mark it as correct if it alleviates the problem somewhat.

Comment: @nickcoding have done! let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to recommend first to update the iOS `Mapbox` and `MapBox Geocoder` SDKs to the latest versions - sometimes these updates fix outstanding bugs in the frameworks.

Next, I'd recommend to wrap the error-causing `geocode` lines in synchronous `DispatchQueue` blocks, like this:

```
func getLocation(from address: String, completion: @escaping (_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?)-> Void) {
      //let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let geocoder = Geocoder(accessToken: "pk.eyJ1Ijoibmlja2JyaW5zbWFkZSIsImEiOiJjazh4Y2dzcW4wbnJyM2ZtY2V1d20yOW4wIn0.LY1H3cf7Uz4BhAUz6JmMww")
    let foptions = ForwardGeocodeOptions(query: address)
    print("hit this point")
    foptions.focalLocation = CLLocation(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)
    DispatchQueue.global().sync {
        geocoder.geocode(foptions) { (placemarks, attribution ,error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks,
                let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate
            else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
          completion(location)
        }
    }
}

func findResults(address: String) {
    let geocoder = Geocoder(accessToken: "pk.eyJ1Ijoibmlja2JyaW5zbWFkZSIsImEiOiJjazh4Y2dzcW4wbnJyM2ZtY2V1d20yOW4wIn0.LY1H3cf7Uz4BhAUz6JmMww")
    let foptions = ForwardGeocodeOptions(query: address)
    foptions.focalLocation = CLLocation(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude)
    foptions.maximumResultCount = 10
    DispatchQueue.global().sync {
        geocoder.geocode(foptions) { (placemarks, attribution ,error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks else {
                return
            }
            self.searchResults = []
            for placemark in placemarks {
                self.searchResults.append(placemark)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't fix the issue, then I'd recommend viewing the various threads in the stack frame in Xcode when the Swift Error breakpoint is raised - you can do this on the left hand panel by tapping on the different thread names. See this:

How to select a thread:
[image: select different thread]

Once you can see the individual lines of code for each thread (tapping each thread on the left, shows this for each of your files), you can add the same `DispatchQueue.global().sync { }` blocks around the conflicting access lines in your code for every single relevant thread. I outline how to select where to place these blocks now.

If you see in the image, for each thread, the call stack is listed from bottom to top. You only need to add the `DispatchQueue.global().sync { }` block around one line where the `data` variable is being accessed. But, if you are accessing the `data` variable inside a completion block (like your geocode functions) then the `DispatchQueue.global().sync { }` needs to go around the whole function.

How to select an error line in `Thread 1`:
[image: error line selection]

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I awarded the bounty, I'll try this out later (keeping my fingers crossed it works), I'll also do the MapBox updates and see what happens, thank you!